# Adicionar um separador a cada item

Tags: html, bootstrap

Olá,

Tenho o site `exemplo.com`, nele eu uso o Bootstrap, gostaria de adicionar uma / a cada item na navbar dele, como um breadcumb.

[image: Breadcumb]

Como se fosse um breadcumb mas na navbar.

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que já tens com código e/ou imagem para ficar mais claro?

Comment: @Sergio código eu não tenho, procurei na internet mas não achei nada que pudesse me ajudar.

Comment: Você nm tem nem o código da navbar ? Providencie algo para as pessoas poderem te ajudar... Uma imagem do que deseja ou um link...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apesar de a sua pergunta estar meio confusa, veja se não é isso aqui que você precisa:

```css
.nav .breadcrumb {
    margin: 0 7px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .nav .breadcrumb {
        float: left;
        margin: 7px 10px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
       
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <ul class="breadcrumb list-inline">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
            <li class="active">Data</li>
          </ul>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Hello George <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign icons-padding"></span> Help</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off icons-padding"></span> Exit</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Fonte: [Breadcrumb into a navbar in bootstrap 3.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20271642/6054930).